# Highchart gauge chart with data from socket.io

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, socket.io

I have a socket.io server that seend data every 2 seconds, and I want to put that data into a gaugue chart that will show the data.

I have this highchart gauge chart that is using the data from the socket, the problem is that the gauge didn't show's the data, but the script send the msg to the console that getting the data.
[image: Console log]
[image: Gauge]

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: container,
        height: 400,
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Humidity'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 89.9,
        background: null,
        center: ['50%', '75%'],
        size: '110%'
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        tickPixelInterval: 72,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.chart.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        tickLength: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        labels: {
            distance: 15,
            style: {
                fontSize: '14px'
            }
        },
        
        lineWidth: 0,
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 20,
                    color: {
                    linearGradient:  { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                    [0, '#ff8000'], //yellow
                    [1, '#DF5353'] //green
                    ]
                    },
            thickness: 30
        }, {
            from: 20,
            to: 40,
                    color: {
                    linearGradient:  { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                    [0, '#DDDF0D'], //yellow
                    [1, '#ff8000'] //green
                    ]
                    },
            thickness: 30
        }, {
            from: 40,
            to: 60,
                    color: {
                    linearGradient:  { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                    [0, '#DDDF0D'], //yellow
                    [1, '#DDDF0D'] //green
                    ]
                    },
            thickness: 30
        }, {
            from: 60,
            to: 80,
                    color: {
                    linearGradient:  { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                    [0, '#DDDF0D'], //yellow
                    [1, '#55BF3B'] //green
                    ]
                    },
            thickness: 30
        }, {
            from: 80,
            to: 100,
                    color: {
                    linearGradient:  { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                    [0, '#55BF3B'], //yellow
                    [1, '#27C0F0'] //green
                    ]
                    },
            thickness: 30
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Humidity',
        data: [0],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' %'
        },
        dataLabels: {
            format: '{y} %',
            borderWidth: 0,
            color: (
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title &&
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
            ) || '#333333',
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        },
        dial: {
            radius: '90%',
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            baseWidth: 12,
            baseLength: '0%',
            rearLength: '0%'
        },
        pivot: {
            backgroundColor: 'gray',
            radius: 6
        }

    }]

});


    var socket = io.connect("http://0.0.0.0:5000");
    socket.on("updateSensorData", function (msg) {
        console.log("Received sensorData :: " + msg.RH);
    const chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    if (chart && !chart.renderer.forExport) {
    const point = chart.series[0].points[0];     
        point.update(msg.RH);
    }});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Whether the returned `msg.RH` is of type `number`?

Comment: No, I don't get any error in the console, and yes is type number I have a spiline chart that is using it

Comment: That's strange behavior and I don't find anything wrong with your chart config, as you can see it works nicely with the fixed number. Perhaps this is a cache thing, or do you have some additional code in your config?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same example and worked fine for me using below code:

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
      var value = parseInt(event.data);
      console.log("On message " + value);
      chart.series[0].points[0].update(value);
 };
```

[image: Example response]

Full Html code is as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Gauge Chart Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.1.0/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart-container" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>

    <script>
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: container,
                height: 400,
                type: 'gauge',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBackgroundImage: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false,
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Humidity'
            },

            pane: {
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 89.9,
                background: null,
                center: ['50%', '75%'],
                size: '110%'
            },

            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                tickPixelInterval: 72,
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                tickColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.chart.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
                tickLength: 30,
                tickWidth: 2,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                labels: {
                    distance: 15,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '14px'
                    }
                },

                lineWidth: 0,
                plotBands: [{
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#ff8000'], //yellow
                            [1, '#DF5353'] //green
                        ]
                    },
                    thickness: 30
                }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#DDDF0D'], //yellow
                            [1, '#ff8000'] //green
                        ]
                    },
                    thickness: 30
                }, {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#DDDF0D'], //yellow
                            [1, '#DDDF0D'] //green
                        ]
                    },
                    thickness: 30
                }, {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#DDDF0D'], //yellow
                            [1, '#55BF3B'] //green
                        ]
                    },
                    thickness: 30
                }, {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#55BF3B'], //yellow
                            [1, '#27C0F0'] //green
                        ]
                    },
                    thickness: 30
                }]
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Humidity',
                data: [10],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' %'
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '{y} %',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    color: (
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.title &&
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                    ) || '#333333',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '16px'
                    }
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '90%',
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    baseWidth: 12,
                    baseLength: '0%',
                    rearLength: '0%'
                },
                pivot: {
                    backgroundColor: 'gray',
                    radius: 6
                }

            }]
        });

        // Set up socket connection
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1234/socket'); // Replace with your socket server's host and port

        // Listen for socket connection established
        socket.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
        };

        // Listen for socket messages
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            var value = parseInt(event.data);
            console.log("On message " + value);
            chart.series[0].points[0].update(value);
        };

    </script>
</body>

</html
```